# Understanding Redux functionality

Tags: redux, react-redux

Hi I have started working as a dev in new company and wanted to understand one peice of redux code, I tried searching through docs but unable to understand how this is working, it will be really great if someone could help me understand the code

```
export function updateData(Id, data) {
  return {
    types: [UPDATE_DATA, PUT_UPDATE_DATA_SUCCESS, PUT_UPDATE_DATA_FAIL],
    quoteId,
    promise: client => client.put(`${DYNAMIC_URL}`, {
      data,
      options: {
        absolute: true
      }
    })
  };
}
```

The above is a action creator which is returning some actions by calling a api and dispatched to a reducer as far as i can understand but what i dont understand is how is multiple types working in an action creator does reducer reduce one by one  if thats so then doesn't the last action PUT_UPDATE_DATA_FAIL will be final result? Posting sample reducer for more understanding

```
 export default function defaultReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
       case UPDATE_DATA:
          return {
              ...state,
              status: STATUS.PENDING
          };
        case PUT_UPDATE_DATA_SUCCESS:
          return {
              ...state,
              status: STATUS.SUCCESS
           };
        case PUT_UPDATE_DATA_FAIL:
          return {
             ...state,
             status:STATUS.FAIL,
             error: action.error.error
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: You got to look at the middleware/enhancer that's used when you call [createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) without that particular middleware you'd probably get an error trying to dispatch such an action.